# Issue with axis rescalling in d3

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

I am playing around with [this example](http://www.janwillemtulp.com/2011/04/01/tutorial-line-chart-in-d3/comment-page-1/#comment-41016) of a line graph using larger data values, e.g.

```
var data = [3567, 6643, 2123, 1447, 1245, 2414]
```

and the y axis isn't starting at 0, instead of 1245. Was wondering if there was a simple way to alter this.

Comment: The y axis should start at 0 with the code you've linked to.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the example code and your data: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/9qz9mgmv/1/ . The y axis starts at 0  (the only other change from the original example is to add an `extramargin` variable so you can see the y-axis tick values). What are you seeing?

Comment: Yeah, thats fixed it. Wasn't so fussed about the ticks. but works great. thanks